# Reorder factor levels after pivot_longer

Tags: r, ggplot2, levels

I am trying to reorder factor levels in a tibble after using `pivot_longer`. Ultimately, the goal is to plot the data in `ggplot` and have the legend align with the order of the lines in the chart. I don't want to manually assign the levels each time. I'd like the factor ordered by one of the variables in the pivoted tibble. But that column has multiple values for each factor...

This has to be easier than I am making it!

Here is my code:

```
df <- tibble(Year=c(1900, 1901, 1903), Foo=c(9,30, 60), Bar=c(3,20, 50)) %>%
 pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = "Name", values_to = "Count")
df$Name <- factor(df$Name)
```

Then `levels(df$Name)` returns the default alphabetical order of `[1] "Bar" "Foo"`. But I'd like to reorder that based on the maximum value each factor has in the `Count` column of the tibble, i.e.  `[1] "Foo" "Bar"` in this case.

All of this is so I can plot the data and align the legend to the order of the lines in the chart (without setting the order of the levels manually). Here is my `ggplot` code:

```
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x = Year, y = Count)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Name))
p
```

And here is the plot:

[image]

Help? Thanks!

Comment: try `df %>% mutate(Name = factor(Name, unique(Name)))`

Comment: Thanks @onyambu -- that didn't seem to work for me. I want to reorder the factor ```Name``` based on the maximum value each factor has in the ```Count``` column of the tibble.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Update

A little bit cumbersome, but we can first create a vector to get the levels order based on the maximum values per factor (here: `foo = 60`, `bar = 50`) and then use it as levels:

```r
fac_order <- df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = "Name", values_to = "Count") %>% 
  distinct(Count, .keep_all = TRUE) %>% 
  slice_max(Count, by = Name) %>%
  arrange(desc(Count)) %>% 
  pull(Name)


df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = "Name", values_to = "Count") %>% 
  mutate(Name = factor(Name, levels = fac_order)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Count)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Name))
```

The result remains the same.

#### First Version

You could use

```r
library(tidyverse)

df1 <- tibble(Year=c(1900, 1901, 1903), Foo=c(9,30, 60), Bar=c(3,20, 50))

df1 %>% 
  pivot_longer(!Year, names_to = "Name", values_to = "Count") %>% 
  mutate(Name = fct_reorder(Name, Count, .desc = TRUE)) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = Year, y = Count)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = Name))
```

This returns

[image]

Comment: You probably mean `mutate(Name = fct_reorder(Name, Count, .desc = TRUE))` (no `df$`)

Comment: @Axeman you are totally right.

Comment: Thanks @Martin Gal. This solution fixes the immediate issue by ordering the factor by reverse alphabetical, right? I want to reorder the factor ```Name``` based on the maximum value each factor has in the ```Count``` column of the tibble. In this case, that's reverse alphabetical, but that's a coincidence. Does that makes sense?

Comment: @tgraybam Based on the maximum value in `Count` summed for the whole data.frame? In your case: `foo = 96, bar = 73`?

Comment: @MartinGal The maximum value in ```Count``` summed of the whole data.frame would work. Or the maximum value for each factor, in this case: ```foo = 60, bar = 50```. That would be fine too. Thanks!

Comment: @tgraybam Made an update. Not totally satisfied tbh.

Comment: Thanks @MartinGal. Totally satisfied or not, it works perfectly! I made one tweak. I think we need ```distinct(Count, .keep_all = TRUE)```  to account for the possibility that ```Count``` has multiple maximum values. (I took the liberty of adding this line to your update. I know that's not the usual protocol and I hope you will forgive me! I will accept your answer. )Thanks again.